# hotswap java code using java 7,spring framework 4.0, eclipselink, oracle 11 db, websphere 7 server

Tags: java, hotswap, bytecode-hot-swap

I worked on play framework and got to know the best feature of it that you dont need to build and publish the code changes to reflect it on UI.You just save the changes and refresh the page you will find your changes on web page.Now i am using java-7, spring-4.0, websphere-7 server, oracle 11-g db and eclipse-link, so can i implement that play like feature in this? if yes then what tool or what configuration i should use? , i am using IBM RSA Development IDE.I found few things on google like Hotswap-Agent , but i am not sure how to use it and configure it or is it good way to use ?.

My question is very simple i mentioned above technologies we are using into our project and i want to avoid build and publish process it will take lot of time every time i make changes into the code and want to see it on web page.